# more congestion than Marshall's sinuses -- what are they talking about?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [TCP/IP For Dummies, 6th Edition by Candace Leiden and Marshall Wilensky (2009)](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470450606.html)

Example:

> First of all, we don’t recommend setting up a host to be both a client and
>   server. Just because something is possible doesn’t mean you should do it. A
>   computer that tries to do everything has **more congestion than Marshall's
>   sinuses**.

What is this in reference to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a joke, referring to the (presumable) fact that one of the authors suffers from congested sinuses.

Answer (score 3):

It's a play on a double meaning of the word "congested" (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**congested**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/congested)
>   *Adjective*
>   **1.** (of a road or place) so crowded with traffic or people as to hinder or
>   prevent freedom of movement:
>   *"the congested streets of the West End"*
>   *"the road was congested with refugees"*
>
> **2.** (of the respiratory tract) blocked with mucus so as to hinder
>   breathing:
>   *"his nose was congested"*

It's also common to refer to the data transmitted on a computer network as "traffic," and hence refer to a network with insufficient capacity as "congested:"

> [**traffic**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/traffic)
>   *Noun*
>   **2.** The messages or signals transmitted through a communications network
>   *"data traffic between remote workstations"*

In this case, it's making a joke about Marshall (Wilensky), one of the authors, who we must assume has frequently-congested sinuses.

Comment: I didn't understand who Marshall was until StoneyB pointed out he's one of the authors.

Comment: @Andrew: I thought it would be clear since the authors are mentioned in the question, but I've added a note about it. Thanks!